# stuck after redirect to graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I have a question. Before my site was normal but today there is a bug:

After a redirect to

[https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=< xx >&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Ffaniticsleague%2Fsessions%2Fcreate&scope=publish_stream,email,user_birthday,offline_access](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%3C%20xx%20%3E&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/faniticsleague/sessions/create&scope=publish_stream,email,user_birthday,offline_access)

My site is stuck.

Could any one help me???

NB: < xx > -> is the secret key from Facebook

Answer (score 1):

'xx' there isn't supposed to be the secret key, it's supposed to be the app ID, which is 126048607473896 for that app - the secret key shouldn't be needed in that call.

Also, `offline_access` is [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/), you should look at the current documentation as well as whatever tutorial you're working from